# What is meant by a "release"?

Tags: theory, terminology

In a [Tom Cosm video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7D3uTgb_ho&list=UUyiC_SKm-R5WLVMYmxuMXxA) on making beats in Ableton Live, he states (12:20):

> See, we have that kind of suck now. That's another kind of tension
>   thing. I find with these kind of tension things, you need a release
>   after or just a few beats after to kind of get them some resolution.

What is he meaning by a "release", and where can I look to get more theory or understanding on that concept?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He’s referring to [tension and release](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tension_%28music%29), an element of music theory which states essentially that music uses tension to create an expectation, followed by a release that fulfills the expectation. Dissonance and consonance are a very common method for tension and release, but you can also use rhythm, dynamics, and other musical elements to create tension and then release it.

For example, when a song gets very quiet, we usually expect it to get loud. When somebody sings *do-re-mi-fa-sol-la-ti,* there’s a strong expectation that they follow with *do.* When somebody knocks the rhythm “shave and a haircut,” we expect “two bits” to follow. All of those are ways of creating *tension,* and the parts that satisfy it are called the *release.*

Answer (score 7):

**Tension and release** is a very important concept in music structure. A lot of chord schemes are built so that a certain chord will cause a feeling of *tension*, which can then be released or prolonged as desired. This is something our ears pick up instinctively; anyone with or without musical knowledge will subconsciously notice this tension and release.

Take a look at [this article](http://i.grahamenglish.net/1033/how-to-use-tension-and-release-in-your-melodies/) if you want an in-depth explanation -- I think it is quite nicely written.

Comment: Ack, beat me by 25 seconds! Nice article on melodic tension and release. I suspect that the video might be using a different kind of tension though. Anyway, +1.